# Adding linked table that refers to an ACCDB file on the network

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm attempting to abstract data sources in an Access application that had been converted to local tables a few days ago. I found an article that suggested renaming the newly-local table and adding a new linked table with the original name.

I have an ACCDB database file uploaded to a network drive that is properly mapped on my machine. I don't have the option to select this database file as my data source. Please help me determine why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this myself - Turned out I was trying to use ODCB linking instead of importing links as Access data sources.